# Difference between comparisons and swaps in insertion sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given below is a pseudocode of insertion sort algorithm applied on array A (zero-based indexing).
        def compare(a, b) :
            if a > b return 1
            else return -1

```
    for i : 1 to length(A)
    j = i - 1
    while j > 0
           if compare(A[j-1], A[j]) > 0
                swap(A[j], A[j-1])
                j = j - 1
           else break
```

Given an array A of integers , find difference between number of compare function calls and number of swap function calls by above algorithm when applied on A.

Let us take an example with A = {1, 2, 4, 3}. If we apply insertion sort as above on A we call sequeunce of compare and swap functions in following order

```
compare (A[0], A[1])
compare (A[1], A[2])
compare (A[2], A[3])
swap       (A[2], A[3])
compare (A[1], A[2])
```

Here compare function is called 4 times, swap function is called 1 time. The answer is 4-1 = 3.

I need to find the difference optimally without running the actual insertion sort algorithm which takes O(n^2).

Comment: "find the difference optimally" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every `i` from `2` to `length(A)` the number of `compare` calls will be one more than the number of `swap` calls besides the situation where the current element is minimal among all elements from `1` to `i` (in this situation we exit from the loop when `j` becomes `0`). The answer will be `length(A)-1 - minimal number occurrences`.

```
minElement = A[1] // one-based array
result = length(A) - 1
for i = 2 to length(A)
    if A[i] < minElement 
        minElement = A[i]
        result = result - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

put a counter in `while` loop and another in `if` condition.
The subtraction of these two will give the answer.

Comment: Last line of the question is about that

Comment: to be more specific the quote is `I need to find the difference optimally without running the actual insertion sort algorithm which takes O(n^2).`

Comment: @DAle I read it now, but I personally think it won't remain insertion sort if we reduce complexity below that. It can be called some other sorting technique then

Comment: @Sandeep, but he does not need to sort elements at all

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev we can do insertion comparison from last inserted element in such case and move forward or backward  from pivot depending on the result whether the number is greater than or less than the pivot.

Comment: @DAle he need to sort actually because it will be needed in next step decision of a particular(here insertion) algorithm. Insertion sort is where we sort element in insertion time only. And if I am wrong please enlightenment me on this.I here to learn